# How to get passed the 'Update BIOS From Drive' screen?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bios

I'm running a dual-boot Windows 7 and Linux Mint machine.
My pc used to work until one day I turned it on and instead of taking me to the OS boot screen, it took me to a BIOS-type screen with 2 real options:

1. Update Bios from drive

clicking this comes up with the message 'No Drive found'

2. Save Bios to drive

clicking takes me to a save as.. screen but it has 0 bytes available

I've checked in BIOS to see if I could see my HDD connected and it says that it's there and number 1 in boot priority.

Not sure where to go from here, any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like Gigabyte Q-Flash. Is your "[end]" key stuck? What happens if you unplug the keyboard (before booting).

Comment: I will try now :)

Comment: @Yorik you are the best <3 it works without plugged in, removed end key and works with keyboard plugged in you're the best